# How to compile packages that has dependencies?

Tags: java

I have implemented a project containing files that are located in 3 separate folders:

1. Operator interface that located in `e:\operator.Operator`
2. Business of the program taht has FileProcess class in `e:\project\main.FileProcess`
3. four classes Plus, Minus, Multiply, Divide that implement Operator interface in `e:\operators.Plus, Minus, Divide, Multiply`

This three folder has dependencies for example: class `Plus`, `Minus`, `Divide`, `Multiply` implement `Operator` interface or class `FileProcess` import `Operator`.

I use command line to compile this codes but I don't know How to do that. When I compile in simple manner(`javac operators/*.java` or `javac main/FileProcess.java`) I get **ClassNotFoundException** or other errors .

Comment: I want compile this classes but becouse they are in separate folder I can't compile them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example to found your error:

. Create two folders `c:\a1\` and `c:\a2\`.

. In `c:\a1\` create `A.java` file:

```
package a1;
import a2.B;

public class A implements B{

    public void metodoB(){
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

. In `c:\a2\` create `B.java` file:

```
package a2;

public interface B{
    public void metodoB();
}
```

. Compile the class and its interface:

```
C:\>javac c:\a1\A.java
```

**EDIT:**

. In `c:\a3\` create `C.java` file:

```
package a3;

import a1.A;
import a2.B;

public class C{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        A a = new A();
        a.metodoB();

    }
}
```

. Compile the Main class:

`C:\>javac c:\a3\C.java`

. Execute the program:

`C:\>java a3.C`

Comment: For two folders it works but I have three folder that 2 of them (operators and project) use Operator interface

Comment: Hi, did you try my example?

Comment: @ lametaweb Hi ,yes I try your examples and I know what the problem was.I should run my program from directory that all folders become visible for jvm and compiler.thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You must run the commands at the same time

`javac operators/*.java main/*.java`

Comment: First I should compile four class in operators folder I do like so  : javac operators/*.java operator/Operator.java then I want to compile the FileProcess class I do like so : javac main/*.java operator/Operator.java but I get NullPointerException the error said I can't find operator/Operator

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Gradle:
https://gradle.org/

This is very convenient way to create project dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use Maven/Ant and import dependencies through it.
Like:

```
     <modules>
        <module>Module1</module>
     </modules>
     <properties>
        //Set version of you module
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>package_name</groupId>
              <artifactId>Artifact_name</artifactId>
              <version>Version you set in properties tag</version>
         </dependency>
     <dependencies>
```